# MySpace integration

Tags: android, http, myspace

I am quite new to the HTTP set of classes. I am trying to integrate MySpace with my android cell phone.

I am able to make a http connection to "mobileservices.myspace.com" and able to do first post(to get the  hash and salt) but when I try to open input stream to get the response, i get a `FileNotFoundException`.

If I open the input stream before opening the output stream to post data, I get same exception during opening the output stream.

So the second opening (be it input stream or output stream) is giving this exception. I have set both flags , `doInput` and `doOutput` to true.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following link for the Android MySpace App

**http://code.google.com/p/myspace-android-sdk/**

The source code for the project is accessible , can checkout that ..can be useful for you

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:
Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.

**svn checkout http://myspace-android-sdk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ myspace-android-sdk-read-only**

Kindly revert for any clarifications.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I figured out the prob.  I had sent the http parameters wrongly. :)